# How to clear drawing on a canvas in Android

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I have already set up the canvas for the drawing. My problem now is how to clear the drawing.

Tried doing this to no avail.

```
public void clear()
{
    circlePath.reset();
    mPath.reset();
    // Calls the onDraw() method
    //invalidate();
}
```

Please take a look at the whole code here:

https://gist.github.com/akosijiji/a29cca90bead2e5e35ad

Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: try the below and inform me if it works. You are better off using a singleton class to initalize your drawing tools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On button click

```
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dv.clear(); // call clear method using in your custom view


        }

    });
```

Define a clear method in your custom view

```
         public void clear()
        {
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height ,
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

            //Added later..
        mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setDither(true);
            mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
            invalidate();
        }
```

Reset all drawing tools and call invalidate to refresh the view.

Complete working code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener {

DrawingView dv ;
RelativeLayout rl;   
    private Paint       mPaint;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dv = new DrawingView(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
    rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
    rl.addView(dv);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    //b.setText(R.string.France);
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    rl.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              // dv.clear();    
             new ColorPickerDialog(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this, mPaint.getColor()).show();


        }

    });

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dv.clear();


        }

    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

 public class DrawingView extends View {

        private int width;
        private  int height;
        private Bitmap  mBitmap;
        private Canvas  mCanvas;
        private Path    mPath;
        private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
        Context context;
        private Paint circlePaint;
        private Path circlePath;

        public DrawingView(Context c) {
        super(c);
        context=c;
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);  
         circlePaint = new Paint();
         circlePath = new Path();
         circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
         circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
         circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
         circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
         circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f); 


        }

        @Override
         protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        width =w;
        height =h;
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

        }
        public void clear()
        {
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height ,
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                //Log.d("BITMAP","Restoring...");
                //mBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length); 

            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

            mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

            //Added later..
            mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setDither(true);
            mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
            invalidate();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

        canvas.drawPath(circlePath, circlePaint);
        }

        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
        }
        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;

             circlePath.reset();
             circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW); 
            // invalidate();

        }
        }
        private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        circlePath.reset();
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
       // mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN));//.Mode.SCREEN));
        mPaint.setMaskFilter(null); 
        mCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN); 

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
        }  
        }
@Override
public void colorChanged(int color) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mPaint.setColor(color);
} 
 }
```

The above works but it is not good design coz everytime you need to clear you will be creating objects like paint object.

You can create singleton class and have your tools reset and then call invalidate

```
 public class DrawingManager {

private static DrawingManager mInstance=null;

public DrawingTools mDrawingUtilities=null;

public int mThemeIndex;

    public Canvas  mCanvas;


    public Path    mPath;

    public Paint   mBitmapPaint;

    public Bitmap  mBitmap;

    public Paint  mPaint; 

private DrawingManager()
{

    resetDrawingTools();
}

public static DrawingManager getInstance()
{
    if(mInstance==null)
    {
        mInstance=new DrawingManager();         
    }

    return mInstance;
}


public void resetDrawingTools()
{

    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenwidth,screenheight ,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

    Path = new Path();
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

    //Added later..
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.Green);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);


}

/**
 * Clears the drawing board.
 */
public static void clearDrawingBoard()
{
    mInstance=null;
}



public void resetBitmapCanvasAndPath() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenwidth,screenheight ,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        //Log.d("BITMAP","Restoring...");
        //mBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length); 

    mCanvas = new Canvas(.mBitmap);

    mPath = new Path();
}
}
```

In your painting class

```
       private DrawingManager mDrawingManager=null;
       mDrawingManager=DrawingManager.getInstance();// initialize drawing tools once
```

Then on button click to clear draw

```
       mDrawingManager.resetBitmapCanvasAndPath();
       invalidate();
```

Comment: So I have to separate DrawingManager class?

Comment: nope have a seperate class for initializing your drawing tools and clearing the draw. Make that class a singleton. Rest of the code can be same. Its a better design. The 1st approach works buts you would be creating unnecessary objects every time you refresh by calling invalidate.

Comment: and also what is PorterDuff?

Comment: @neknekmouh if you don't get it let me know

Comment: Okay I'll go read it. Thanks. For now, my app is working. I'll accept ur answer.

Comment: maybe you could help me with my new problem regarding animation this is the link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397700/android-animate-imageview

Comment: @neknekmouh no idea about that topic.

Answer (score 0):

you should use yourpaintlayout.removeallviews();

you would have added one layout to your drawing canvas class. You will have option to remove all views from your drawing layout. hope this will help you.