# Animate ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-animation, android-imageview

Currently I'm developing a game.

This is the details of my game:
User should choose the correct image object. 
I want the images to accelerate from left to right. and when they reach the end, they should re-appear on the activity again.

This is the screenshot of what I'm working on:

[image]

I have 5 imageviews and they should accelerate. Do you have sample code for this type of animation? Any help is truly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
Tried doing this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:duration="2000"/>
    </set>
```

But it just slides from left, and no continuation of animation..

Comment: Can't you just increase X of each car and repaint it in a loop with just a condition (if x==finalX) then (x=0/initial pos) ?

Comment: @AsierAranbarri can you show me some sample code? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [Frame Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame) :

In your java file :

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(your Resource);
AnimationDrawable animte = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();
animte.start();
```

Probably, this will help you .

Comment: Hi I think frame animation is not what I'm looking for. Can you please check my edited post.. thanks

Comment: Yeah i will surely look in to it. I will get back to you later after checking it out .