# Infinite animation of imageview android

Tags: java, android, animation, imageview

This is just a continuation of my unsolved question which can be found here: [Animate ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397700/animate-imageview)

For now, I managed to make the imageviews move using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
<translate
android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
android:toXDelta="0%"
android:duration="2000"/>
</set>
```

But what I want to accomplish is the images should accelerate from left to right and when they reach the end, they should re-appear on the activity again.

Any help and suggestion are truly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `android:repeatCount=infinite` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To repeat animation put:

```
android:repeatCount="-1"
```

If you wanna imageView reappear from right to left put:

```
android:repeatMode="reverse"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SurfaceView` instead of moving `ImageViews`.