# Animation of changing ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, imageview, android-motionlayout

My xml form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container_quick_process"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/scene_fragment_quick_process">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        />
```

I want change the picture smoothly in ImageView (filled circle with a half-empty), and bind this animation with MotionLayout's animation

Answer (score 0):

We're going to need a little more info than that. Try this and post a new question with what you tried and didn't get to work [Animate ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397700/animate-imageview)

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear exactly what effect you are trying to achieve.

ConstraintLayout/MotionLayout library provides a Component
ImageFilterView
Which can:

- Cross fade between 2 images
- Change Contrasts/Hue/Saturation/Color Temperature
- pan/zoom/rotate
- clip round the corners from full circle to rounded rect to rectangle
- ImageFiterButton has similar API but is a button with Shadow.

These can be access through MotionLayout's CustomAttribute tag

If you want a vector animation you can use LottieAnimationView (see [Lottie](https://airbnb.design/lottie/))
LottieAnimationView has a setProgress which can be driven from MotionLayout.
[See section on Lottie Animation in Introduction to MotionLayout III](https://medium.com/google-developers/introduction-to-motionlayout-part-iii-47cd64d51a5)

Comment: I used ImageFilterView, but the first circle faded out against the background of the second, but I want it to animate into it

Comment: to cross fade between the two 
set:
app:overlay="false"

But it will not morph between the two.
You can design your own morph using.
https://shapeshifter.design/